# Sorting Merged Eloquent Collections Multiple Keys

Tags: php, laravel-collection

I have two collections that both have a `min` and `max` column. The `min` column is required, the `max` column is nullable, let's call them `cars` and `trucks`

```php
$collection = $cars->merge($trucks);
```

Now I need to sort them first by `max` if it's not `null`, and `min` if it is, then descending.

I read the docs and understand that `sort` is built on `uasort` but I'm still not seeing how to sort by conditional values.

We use a `raw` query on both collections that does this sorting on the collections individually so they are both sorted this way already, but then they lose this sorting when they're merged.

The relationship query looks like so:

```php
return $this->hasMany(Truck::class)->select(
  ['trucks.*', DB::raw('(CASE 
    WHEN max IS NULL THEN min
    ELSE max
    END) as max_min'),
  ]
)->orderBy('max_min', 'desc');
```

I need to replicate this sorting on the merged collection.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way `usort` works internally you need to use it twice to sort according to the rules you have mentioned. Supposing `$collection` holds the merged result you can do something like this

```
//convert to native array
$cars = $collection->toArray();

//bring all items up who have max as null
usort($cars, function($a,$b)
{
    if (is_null($a['max']) && is_null($b['max'])) return 0;
    else return is_null($a['max'])?-1:1;
});

//now sort by the rule
usort($cars, function($a,$b)
{
   if(!is_null($a['max']) && !is_null($b['max'])){
      // MAX can be used for comparison
      if ($a['max']==$b['max']) return 0;
      else return ($a['max']<$b['max'])?-1:1;
   }else{
      // nulled max take preference over non-nulled ones
      if(is_null($a['max']) && !is_null($b['max'])) return -1;
      if(!is_null($a['max']) && is_null($b['max'])) return 1;

      // have to use MIN
      if ($a['min']==$b['min']) return 0;
      return ($a['min']<$b['min'])?-1:1;
   }
});


//convert back to collection object
$cars = collect($cars);
```

The above implementation is for sorting in ascending order

Comment: thanks for your help, but this is easily done with `sortByDesc`. I've posted the answer above. I appreciate your time though.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was far easier than expected.

```php
$collection = $cars->merge($trucks)->sortByDesc(function($item) {
  return !is_null($item['max']) ? $item['max'] : $item['min'];
})
->values()
->all();

return collect($collection);
```

Hopefully this will help someone else.